# Where to find jQuery vulnerabilites?

Tags: jquery

I suspect an old version of jQuery 1.4.4 on a website as been exploited to add some JS and html to the site. Where can I find an index over vulnerabilites for the version 1.4.4?

Comment: Javascript runs on the clientside, so there are very few possiblities of injecting code into your site that way, it's probably a server security problem, SQL, cookies etc.

Comment: What? Vulnerabilites? It is something you look into the backend, not some front-end JS library. Nevertheless, you can examine the changelogs from version 1.4 and up by using the search feature on the jQuery blog http://blog.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=jQuery+1.5+release&go=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not have vulnerabilities because it runs on the client side where *everything* is wide open (so you could say that everything jQuery can touch is already as vulnerable as it can ever be).

The website's server-side code, however, evidently does have some security issues.

Comment: What about Cross-site scripting(XSS) attack?

Comment: XSS attacks are result of poorly written server side code where user input is not properly encoded. It has strictly nothing to do with javascript and even less with jQuery.

Comment: @Railsbeginner: XSS is the result of server-side code sending to a user content produced by another user without properly validating it.

Comment: Are there any online free tool to test for vulnerabilities?

Comment: No, there aren't. If there were, hackers would be unemployed. What I would recommend you is start reading online materials about the server side framework you are using and best practices to secure it. But if you expect to find a tool where you will enter the name of your site and it's gonna tell you that your site has issues or not, either the tool you find is not something that you should trust or simply you won't find it.

Comment: This did show up on(once) the website: http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/29635-malware-on-this-forum/page__st__20 see #24 and #35 the admin says it is server side and I hope that is the case.. Just want to be 110% sure..

Comment: and it is a website with Sitecake version 1.0.14....

Comment: Definitely not the case, take for instance DOM-based Cross-site scripting which is a client-side based vulnerability - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS

Comment: @Juxhin, those attacks are the result of a vulnerability in the server-side code, not in jQuery. You could write the exact same vulnerabilities without any jQuery at all.

Comment: @Jon that's not entirely true, my point was not related to jQuery, as anything you can write in jQuery can effectively be written in vanilla Javascript. My point is that not all vulnerabilities are server-bound, DOM-based XSS being one of them which can be entirely client-side. To such an extent that traditional scanners are incapable of detecting such vulnerabilities due to that very nature :-). I would definitely suggest going over the following post - http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/dom-xss-explained/

Comment: @Juxhin alright, "server side" is perhaps not a good description but it's still the logic that is vulnerable, not anything specifically related to the client side code or jQuery like you say. The end result doesn't really change: the discussion is way out of scope for the question.